# Does jmeter work with webseal?

Tags: jmeter, webseal, badboy

I've trying to make some jmeter test to work with webseal. 
The test were working fine without it even in https but with webseal I get 302 and 404 error on some of my httprequest while other work just fine.

But according to this page : http://90kts.com/2008/10/27/performance-testing-spnego-or-kerberos-with-loadrunner/
jmeter and webseal don't work.

I'm probably reading it wrong but I can't seem to find info about the usage of those 2 product together.

Anybody have experience using jmeter and webseal or should I look for a alternative load test product ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is neither jmeter or webseal but how badboy was exporting the request in jmeter.
The implementation fo the http request need to be httpclient4 in order for the login to work but badboy was settin git to java by default.

And the path saved by badboy is plain wrong, it giving the sub path were has the initial request (which was working) was a level higher.

**working: /parent_path/Apps/servlet**

**badboy: /Apps/servlet**

however this seem to not be a problem in a environement without webseal.